# Database Navigation in VB and SQL

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I am using VB.net 2010 and sql server 2008. I want to have data navigation buttons like next, previous, last , first etc. I am using data reader object to accomplish database manipulation. Now, I want to show Next database row, on Next button press, and same with previous etc.
How can I do that??
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do what you're looking to do with a DataReader, as it returns a read-only, **forward-only** stream of data from a database.

There's some good reading from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931%28v=vs.90%29.aspx on the differences between DataReaders and DataAdapters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WinForms, the easiest solution would be to use a Dataset, BindingSource, DataGridView, and BindingNavigator:

1. Add a Dataset to your project and configure it to pull the data you
   want
2. Drag the Dataset you've created, the TableAdapter used to fill
   it, a BindingSource, a BindingNavigator, and a DataGridView from the
   toolbox onto the form you're designing
3. Bind the BindingSource to the datatable in the dataset, the DataGridView to the BindingSource, and the BindingNavigator to the BindingSource
4. In the form's Load event, fill the datatable with the tableadapter

You'll have to figure out the details, but there's a lot of walkthroughs on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zhc8d2f.aspx)

and elsewhere

Comment: Can I do it with SqlDataReader, as my whole application is based on it

Comment: As Hobbes points out above, the SqlDataReader is forward only; thus you can't navigate backwards using it.  HOwever, I believe you can fill a datatable using a SqlDataReader